# MongoDB: find value in Array with multiple criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to filter documents based on their price range,

i have the following document structure example

```
{
    "name": "test 1",
    "priceObject" : [
        {
            "price" : {
                "value" : 1000
            }
        },
        {
            "price" : {
                "value" : 500
            }
        },
        {
            "price" : {
                "value" : 333
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

i use aggregate to match documents that have at least one price that **must** be greater than 500 and less than 1000

```
{
    "$match": {
        "priceObject.price.value": {
            "$gt": 500,
            "$lt": 1000
        }
    }
}
```

it return "test 1" document, although it should not, because

1. 500 is not less than 1000 and greater that 500
2. 1000 is not less than 1000 and greater that 500
3. 333 is not less than 1000 and greater that 500

how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify more than one condition to query an array then you have to use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples) query operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "priceObject": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "price.value": {
          "$gt": 500,
          "$lt": 1000
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```